# Spinor Commutator in Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, dirac-equation

In (3.87, page. 53) Peskin and Schroeder write $$\psi(\vec{x}) = \int\frac{d^{3}p}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\vec{p}}}} e^{i\vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}} \sum_{s=1,2} (a_{\vec{p}}^{s}u^{s}(\vec{p}) + b_{-\vec{p}}^{s}v^{s}(-\vec{p}))  $$ and then compute

$$[\psi(\vec{x}),\psi^{\dagger}(\vec{y})]=\int\frac{d^3p d^3q}{(2\pi)^{6}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\vec{p}} 2E_{\vec{q}}}} e^{i(\vec{p} \cdot {\vec{x}}-\vec{q} \cdot {\vec{y}})}  \sum_{r,s} ([a_{\vec{p}}^{r},a_{\vec{q}}^{s \dagger}] u^{r}(\vec{p}) \bar{u}^{s}(\vec{q}) + [b_{\vec{p}}^{r},b_{\vec{q}}^{s \dagger}] v^{r}(-\vec{p}) \bar{v}^{s}(-\vec{q})) \gamma^{0}$$

Where does the $ \gamma^{0} $ at the end come from?

Comment: At a glance: $\overline{\psi} =\psi^\dagger \gamma^0$, so since you have $\psi^\dagger$ in the LHS and $\overline{u}, \overline{v}$ in the RHS, a $\gamma^0$ has to show up to account for the difference between dagger and bar.

Answer (score 3):

$u^\dagger = \bar u \, \gamma^0$ and similarly for $v^\dagger$.